# Отправить спустя некоторое время

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Всем привет. Я использую в своем проекте node js и websocket. Нужно сделать так, чтобы например пользователь указал через 2 дня отправить сообщение соединению ws. Как это реализовать?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/timers-in-node/

Comment: Я знаю о существовании setTimeout. Например пользователь хочет отправить через 1 день, 2 часа. Как это записать в этом событии?

Comment: Ну раз вы знаете о `setTimeout`, то должны знать, что передается вторым параметром. Знаете?

Comment: 1м - вызов функции, 2м - через сколько миллисекунд оно выполнится. Так ведь?

Comment: Все верно. Теперь можете 1 день и 2 часа перевести в миллисекунды?

Comment: Да. Но я хотел бы узнать, если запустить больше 100 setTimeout'ов, будет ли большая нагрузка на сервер?

Comment: Просто пользователь может высылать такое сообщение несколько раз

Comment: Этого вопроса в вопросе совсем нету:( Вообще setTimeout ресурсы не отъедает. Только учтите, что при рестарте ноды все установленные setTimeout  конечно же пропадут.

Comment: Да, знаю, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Для персистентного хранения и обработки таких отложенных задач нельзя использовать setTimeout, но можно использовать например Redis Keyspace Notifications - https://redis.io/topics/notifications.